# freeing memory issue

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I have an issue regarding freeing memory as under:

```
            string points; // some points sequences

    char* charPoints = (char*)malloc((points.length() +1) * sizeof(char));

            //do something

    free(charPoints);
```

Even then after freeing memory is leaked when checked with instruments

Comment: If you are using C++, you should use new and delete.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overwriting thye pointer `charPoints` with someother value (or may be incrementing the pointer to end) inside the `\\do something` part. If yes, then there is no memory leak.

Comment: @Alexander I think there is no wrong using C++ and C at parallely time

Comment: @Naveen Yes, i am incrementing the charPoints pointer and doing some complex computation, does it affect to memory.

Comment: If you are incrementing the charPoints pointer, you can no longer pass it to `free()`. The argument you pass to free must be the original pointer that was returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: @Martin That means if that is the case there will be always a memory leak.

Comment: Obviously, the memory leak is happening in the line that says `// do something`

Comment: Ok then wat shoud i do not to occur memory leak.

Comment: @iSight: typically the pointer you get back from malloc is not at the start of the memory block.  Most implementations put information about the size of the block just before the pointer and possibly also some magic number to guard against passing an invalid pointer to free.  If you increment charPoints, free will no longer see that information.  Best case, it will silently do nothing.  Worst case, it will corrupt the heap.

Comment: you didn't show us what "do something" was doing, and the error was there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer you pass to `free` must be the same one which returned by `malloc`. If you pass a different pointer it will result in a undefined behavior. Take a copy of the pointer before you do the operation such as incrementing the `charPoints` and then pass this original pointer to `free` function to properly release memory.

Comment: To garantee this you can make it const: `char* const charPoints = (char*)malloc((points.length() +1) * sizeof(char)); `

Comment: @Charles if this is the case, even if i increment the pointer will it work.

Comment: No this just prevents you from incrementing the pointer.
Take a copy of the pointer and increment that.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is when malloc returns NULL because it can't allocate enough contiguous memory. Are you sure that the memory leak is due to the malloc/free?

Comment: i have checked using instruments. it showed the memory leak at that point.

Comment: At which point? After free of the char variable? The leak may be shown due to other elements allocated and not freed. Would help if you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your instruments for leak detection are bad.

Answer (score 0):

After freeing the memory update with NULL value shown bellow

free(charPoints); 
charPoints ="NULL"